# Equivalent of SQL ISNULL in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, isnull

In SQL you can run a ISNULL(null,'') how would you do this in a linq query?

I have a join in this query:

```
var hht = from x in db.HandheldAssets
        join a in db.HandheldDevInfos on x.AssetID equals a.DevName into DevInfo
        from aa in DevInfo.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
        AssetID = x.AssetID,
        Status = xx.Online
        };
```

but I have a column that has a bit type that is non nullable (xx.online) how can I set this to false if it is null?

Comment: Do you mean "aa.Online" ? "xx" isn't defined anywhere...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Since `aa` is the set/object that might be null, can you check `aa == null` ?

(`aa` / `xx` might be interchangeable (a typo in the question); the original question talks about `xx` but only defines `aa`)

i.e.

```
select new {
    AssetID = x.AssetID,
    Status = aa == null ? (bool?)null : aa.Online; // a Nullable<bool>
}
```

or if you want the default to be `false` (not `null`):

```
select new {
    AssetID = x.AssetID,
    Status = aa == null ? false : aa.Online;
}
```

---

Update; in response to the downvote, I've investigated more... the fact is, this is the right approach! Here's an example on Northwind:

```
        using(var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            ctx.Log = Console.Out;
            var qry = from boss in ctx.Employees
                      join grunt in ctx.Employees
                          on boss.EmployeeID equals grunt.ReportsTo into tree
                      from tmp in tree.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new
                             {
                                 ID = boss.EmployeeID,
                                 Name = tmp == null ? "" : tmp.FirstName
                        };
            foreach(var row in qry)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", row.ID, row.Name);
            }
        }
```

And here's the TSQL - pretty much what we want (it isn't `ISNULL`, but it is close enough):

```
SELECT [t0].[EmployeeID] AS [ID],
    (CASE
        WHEN [t2].[test] IS NULL THEN CONVERT(NVarChar(10),@p0)
        ELSE [t2].[FirstName]
     END) AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS [test], [t1].[FirstName], [t1].[ReportsTo]
    FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2] ON ([t0].[EmployeeID]) = [t2].[ReportsTo]
-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) []
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.1
```

QED?

Comment: Hard to keep rep over 200 per day!?!?! Yeah, right.
I checked [System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.aspx) and there's no method there to ensure SQL's `ISNULL` is produced so I'll be using your code :-)

Comment: What about doing a JOIN with ISNULL?  Will the same thing work? is it necessary?

Comment: Yeah and I tried this and close enough didn't cut it. it created a case statement so when I ran it, it returned too much data. After I removed the case statement, the sql came back fine... sorry got to demote this

Comment: As @dumbledad said, there is no method that will ensure SQL's ISNULL. But since CASE approach has the same result and performance as ISNULL(https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1656650-3412-1.aspx), this is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the `??` operator to set the default value but first you must set the `Nullable` property to `true` in your **dbml** file in the required field (`xx.Online`)

```
var hht = from x in db.HandheldAssets
        join a in db.HandheldDevInfos on x.AssetID equals a.DevName into DevInfo
        from aa in DevInfo.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
        AssetID = x.AssetID,
        Status = xx.Online ?? false
        };
```

Comment: You don't have to modify your dbml. You can just cast `xx.Online` to a nullable int. `Status = ((int?)xx.Online ?? false)`

Answer (score 2):

I often have this problem with sequences (as opposed to discrete values).  If I have a sequence of ints, and I want to SUM them, when the list is empty I'll receive the error "InvalidOperationException: The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.".

I find I can solve this by casting the sequence to a nullable type.  SUM and the other aggregate operators don't throw this error if a sequence of nullable types is empty.

So for example something like this

```
MySum = MyTable.Where(x => x.SomeCondtion).Sum(x => x.AnIntegerValue);
```

becomes

```
MySum = MyTable.Where(x => x.SomeCondtion).Sum(x => (int?) x.AnIntegerValue);
```

The second one will return 0 when no rows match the where clause. (the first one throws an exception when no rows match).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the type is boolean and therefore can never be null and should be false by default.

Comment: How can you make it false by default if its from a join?

Comment: It will be false by default surely?  It is a boolean and has not been set, so it should be false.  What are you seeing?