# How to use isnull type decision in linqdatasource orderby?

Tags: linq, sql-order-by, isnull

I have a sql stored procedure that uses isnull in the order by clause to order items by the latest reply date, or if that is null, by the posting date:

Example:
ORDER BY isnull(rtb.LatestReplyDate,CB_TOPIC_DATE_POSTED) DESC

I am trying to get that to work in the orderby clause of a linqdatasource, to no avail yet:
Example:

I know isnull isn't valid there, but I have yet to figure out what would work, if anything. I tried the ?? operator as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Check this linq..err...link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413084/linq-isnull)

--Addendum

```
OrderBy(p => p.<YourCompareVariant> == null ? p.<IfNull> :  p.<IfNotNull>);
```

In your case:

```
OrderBy(p => p.LatestReplyDate == null ? p.LatestReplyDate : p.TopicDatePosted);
```

Comment: I've already seen that, but it's not exactly what I was looking for. I was wondering if there was a way to very simply apply an isnull to the declarative linqdatasource, rather than messing around programatically in the code behind.

Comment: @Michael pls see edit...is that something on the lines youre looking for

Answer (score 1):

@Xencor, here's what worked:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource OrderBy="(CB_DATE_LATEST_REPLY != null ? CB_DATE_LATEST_REPLY : CB_TOPIC_DATE_POSTED) desc" Select="new (CB_TOPIC_ID, CB_TOPIC_CAT_ID, CB_TOPIC_TITLE, CB_TOPIC_DATE_POSTED, CB_TOPIC_REPLY_COUNT, CB_DATE_LATEST_REPLY, LU_CB_CATEGORy, VIEW_ALL_USER)" TableName="CB_TOPICs" > </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Which is obvious, I don't know how I managed to miss that. Such is life. Thanks for pointing me in right direction.