# How can I get LINQ to SQL to use IS NULL when querying with a null variable?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I looked through the related questions and couldn't find anything pertaining to my situation.

I've got a query that looks like this.

```
var tempFoo = "";
var foo = tempFoo != "" ? tempFoo : null;

var result = Entities.Where(x => x.Bar == foo);
```

`Bar` is a `string` and a nullable `varchar`

The problem is that when `foo` is `null` the SQL generated by LINQ to SQL is:

```
([t0].[Bar] = @p0)
```

where is should be:

```
([t0].[Bar] IS NULL)
```

If I substitute `foo` with `null` in the expression LINQ to SQL uses the correct `IS NULL` syntax. Sometimes, however, `foo` isn't null so I have to use a variable.

**So how can I get LINQ to SQL to use `IS NULL` when `foo` is `null` and `=` when `foo` is not `null` ?**

PS: The reason for the strange variable assignment is because `tempFoo` is referencing a named regex capture. If the capture is empty the value is `""` so I have to check for an empty value and assign `null` instead.

**Thanks!**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of SQL ISNULL in LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413084/equivalent-of-sql-isnull-in-linq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an article on this topic here: http://blog.linqexchange.com/index.php/how-to-use-is-null-with-linq-to-sql/

Comment: Thanks! I really thought there would be a more elegant way than using two different expressions but oh well!

Comment: The link is dead and the other question mentioned above does not address my issue. The best I can gather from the above comment and the answer below is the need for two different LINQ statements - one if "foo" is null and a second if "foo" is not.

Answer (score 1):

As the link that Dan posted, to solve you can use: 
var result = Entities.Where(x => ((foo == null && x.Bar == null) || (x.Bar == foo));

It works for me!