# How to write SQL IsNull() in Linq?

Tags: .net, wpf, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of SQL ISNULL in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413084/equivalent-of-sql-isnull-in-linq)

I am recently migrated from `ADO.Net` to `Entity Framework`

I have problem in executing this query in Linq

```
select IsNull(MAX(InvoiceNo),0) from Sales
```

I have written this query in LINQ except isNull()

```
        var q = (from p in dbContext.Sales
                 select p.InvoiceNo).Max();
```

But i dont know how to use `IsNull()` in this Linq

When i execute this Linq Query I am getting this exception.

> 'The invocation of the constructor on type
>   'JIMS.ViewModel.Transaction.SalesViewModel' that matches the specified
>   binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '8' and line
>   position '6'.

I am using WPF MVVM FrameWork with Entity FrameWork as DAL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var InvoiceNo = dbContext.Sales.Max(x => (int?)x.InvoiceNo) ?? 0;
```

Comment: Is this also Linq or Anonymous Method

Comment: but `??` works only on nullable int `int?` so its throwing an Exception

Comment: Just cast it to a nullable object (int?)x.InvoiceNo if the underlying type is not nullable

Comment: which is faster Lambda Express or Linq

Comment: Both is linq actually, one is query syntax and the other lambda syntax. The performance is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var q = (from p in dbContext.Sales
                 select (int?)p.InvoiceNo).Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to selectzero if invoicno is null. One way you could do this would be:

```
var elements = (from p in dbContext.Sales
                 where p.InvoiceNo != null
                 select p.InvoiceNo).Max();
```

Assuming there'll always be at least one invoiceno if not you can do

```
var elements = (from p in dbContext.Sales
                 select p.InvoiceNo ?? 0).Max();
```

which will have to compare all elements so it *could* be slower than the first approach