# LINQ doesn't work with a "select isnull" query..?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of SQL ISNULL in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413084/equivalent-of-sql-isnull-in-linq)
>   [Using IsNull or select COALESCE in Linq..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064177/using-isnull-or-select-coalesce-in-linq)

I've tried this query in LINQ:

```
   string query = @"SELECT ISNULL(P.firstname, s.firstname) AS Expr1,ISNULL(P.lastname,
  s.lastname) AS Expr2 FROM comment AS C LEFT OUTER JOIN professor AS P ON P.ID =   

  C.PID LEFT OUTER JOIN student AS s ON s.ID = C.SID

  WHERE (C.VID = 2)";

        ArrayList allNames=null;
        using (var context = new NewsReaderEntities())
        {
            ObjectQuery<string> results = context.CreateQuery<string>(query);
         //   ObjectQuery<string> results1 = context.CreateQuery<string>
             (query1,parameters);
            foreach (string result in results )
            {
                allNames.Add(result);

            }
        }

        return allNames;



    }
```

but it returns the error:

> linq 'ISNULL' cannot be resolved into a valid type or function. Near
>   simple identifier,

I've also tried this query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(p.firstname, s.firstname), COALESCE(p.lastname, s.lastname)
  FROM comment c
  LEFT JOIN Professor p
    ON c.pid = p.id
  LEFT JOIN Student s
    ON c.sid = s.id
 WHERE c.vid = 2
```

This also raises an error.

Both work okay in SQL Management. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a google search "linq isnull" - it returns this SO question which I believe will answer your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413084/equivalent-of-sql-isnull-in-linq

Answer (score 0):

See this example:

```
var query = from p in Pets select p;
if (OwnerID != null) query = query.Where(x => x.OwnerID == OwnerID);
if (AnotherID != null) query = query.Where(x => x.AnotherID == AnotherID);
if (TypeID != null) query = query.Where(x => x.TypeID == TypeID);
```

Hope this help you