# Using IsNull or select COALESCE in Linq..?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of SQL ISNULL in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413084/equivalent-of-sql-isnull-in-linq)

I have 3 tables like this :

comment table :

```
commentId pid    sid       text      vid
1          1     null    comment 1    1
2         null    1     comment 2    1
3          2     null    comment 3    1
```

student table

```
sid     firstname   lastname
1         john       adam
2         joan       adam
```

professor table :

```
pid    firstname   lastname
1       mark        abram
2       sean        hoak
```

I want to make a query so the result to return like this :

```
firstname    lastname
mark          abram
john          adam
sean          hoak
```

m

```
if (select query ==null) then (selec query 1) else select (query 2)
```

i tried the following :

```
if((select pid from comment==null)
then select student.firstname , student.lastname from student where sid in (select sid from comment where vid=1)

else
(select professor.firstname ,professor.lastname from professor where pid in (select pid from comment where vid=1)
```

but with no use

then others provided this solution queries

IsNull Query

```
SELECT ISNULL(P.firstname, s.firstname) AS Expr1,ISNULL(P.lastname, s.lastname) AS Expr2
FROM comment AS C 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN professor AS P ON P.ID = C.PID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN student AS s ON s.ID = C.SID
WHERE (C.VID = 2)
```

COALESCE:

```
  SELECT COALESCE(p.firstname, s.firstname), COALESCE(p.lastname, s.lastname)
  FROM comment c
  LEFT JOIN Professor p
  ON c.pid = p.id
 LEFT JOIN Student s
  ON c.sid = s.id
   WHERE c.vid = 2
```

both works fine in SQL Management , but in Linq with the:

```
ObjectQuery<string> results1 = context.CreateQuery<string>(query1, parameters)
```

I've tried to convert it my self to :

```
var qry = from c in ctx.comment
  join p in ctx.professor
  on c.PID equals p.ID into tree
  join s in ctx.student
  on c.SID equals s.ID into tree1
  where c.VID == vID
  from tmp in tree.DefaultIfEmpty()
  from tmp1 in tree.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new
  {
      Firstnmae = tmp.firstname ?? tmp1.firstname,
      LastName = tmp.lastname ?? tmp1.lastname
  };
```

but it returns null

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have a typo near `tmp1`, you should do `tree1.DefaultIfEmpty()`

```
      var qry = from c in ctx.comment
      join p in ctx.professor
      on c.PID equals p.ID into tree
      join s in ctx.student
      on c.SID equals s.ID into tree1
      where c.VID == vID
      from tmp in tree.DefaultIfEmpty()
      from tmp1 in tree1.DefaultIfEmpty()
      select new
      {
          Firstnmae = tmp.firstname ?? tmp1.firstname,
          LastName = tmp.lastname ?? tmp1.lastname
      };
```

Comment: Post error to get specific issue addressed.