# Using ISNULL function in EntityDataSource CommandText

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entitydatasource

I wrote below query in `EntityDataSource CommandText`.

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME + ' ' + ISNULL(LAST_NAME, '') AS Customer
FROM CUSTOMER
```

but there is an error as `isnull cannot be resolved into valid type or function`.

how cold i solve this ? what should i use instead of `ISNULL` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of SQL ISNULL in LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413084/equivalent-of-sql-isnull-in-linq)

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi i tried it. but got an error with `?` use in there.

Comment: try COALESCE => COALESCE(LAST_NAME,'')

Comment: @tr3 got error as `The query syntax is not valid. Near term '>'`

Comment: did you allow LAST_NAME to be NULL in CUSTOMER table, in its design ?

Comment: @Nathan yes. `LAST_NAME` is nullable column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for `ISNULL` in entity sql. You'll have to resort to [`CASE WHEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399229.aspx):

```
CASE
    WHEN LAST_NAME IS NULL THEN '' 
    ELSE LAST_NAME 
END
```

Can't help it.