# Apply ISNULL like SQL in LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq, t-sql, linq-to-entities, isnull

I have the next LINQ where **o.Value** and **p.Value** are decimal types

```
from o in dbContext.Ammounts
where o.Value > (from p in dbContext.Payments select p).Sum(p => p.Value))
```

The inner LINQ `from p in dbContext.Payments select p).Sum(p => p.Value)` can be return a NULL value and I need to apply a `ISNULL(linq_sentence, 0)`

I try with this:

```
from o in dbContext.Ammounts
where o.Value > ((from p in dbContext.Payments select p).Sum(p => p.Value)) ?? 0m)
```

But I get this message error:

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and
>   'decimal'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413084/equivalent-of-sql-isnull-in-linq Duplication !!

Comment: The error message should be perfectly clear: you have a non-nullable `decimal` on the left side of the `??` operator, so you do not need the `??` there at all (or you need to change your mapping to tell LINQ2SQL that the column is nullable).

Comment: How can you null coalesce a non-nullable type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the collection is empty in Linq2SQL the aggregate returns `null`. If the value being aggregated is non nullable this will throw an exception. To solve the problem, cast the value being aggregated to a nullable type.

```
from o in dbContext.Ammounts
where o.Value > ((from p in dbContext.Payments select p)
                .Sum(p => (decimal?)p.Value)) ?? 0m);
```

More info: http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/07/15/applying-aggregates-to-empty-collections-causes-exception-in-linq-to-sql.aspx