# SQL stored procedure to linq

Tags: sql, linq

I'm trying to convert a stored procedure to linq but i have gone stuck on the last part where is says

```
   WHERE 
    ISNULL([feature].featuretypegroup, @id) = @id AND LanguageParameters.company = @company
```

What does the function ISNULL and how do i translate this to linq?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of SQL ISNULL in LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413084/equivalent-of-sql-isnull-in-linq)

Comment: Can you show the entire query?

Comment: why would you take a working stored proc and comnvert it to linq. WHy not just call it in linq?